Find out $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(-x^2+x+1)}{x(1-x)} \rm{d}x$ without Feynman .
Find out $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(-x^2+x+1)}{x(1-x)} \rm{d}x$$.
They say when it comes to logarithms in integrals first thing to check if $[x → \frac{1}{x}]$ works or not .
My try :
$$I = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(-x^2+x+1)}{x(1-x)} \rm{d}x = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(\frac{-1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x} + 1)}{\frac{1}{x}(1-\frac{1}{x})}.\frac{-1}{x^2} \rm{d}x [x → \frac{1}{x}] = - \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(\frac{x^2+x-1}{x^2})}{x-1} \rm{d}x = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2\ln(x)}{x-1} \rm{d}x - \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x^2+x-1)}{x-1} \rm{d}x$$
No idea how to proceed further , all the approaches are welcome (except Feynman ones) .

Is it possible that you have forgotten to change the limits of integration?

@SeverinSchraven no I don't think so

Ok, then how did you replace $x$ by $1/x$ without needing to adapt the limits of integration?

@SeverinSchraven thanks sir the limits now feels lil interesting to deal with

Now you can see that you cannot split the integral as you did in the end as the first one will be $\infty$ while the second one is $-\infty$.

@SeverinSchraven what do u mean is it still incorrect ??

The very last step is not correct. It is like saying $\int_1^\infty 0 = \int_1^\infty (-x) dx + \int_1^\infty x dx$. The integrals are not finite.

@SeverinSchraven ok I thought u were concerned about the signs only

Does "all approaches" include contour integration?

No sorry can't include it

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(-x^2+x+1)}{x(1-x)} \ dx \\
=  &\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(-x^2+x+1)}{x} \ dx
+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(-x^2+x+1)}{1-x} \overset{x\to 1-x}{dx}\\
 = &\ 2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(-x^2+x+1)}{x} \ dx\\
 = &\ 2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-\frac1{\phi}x)}{x} \ dx
+ 2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+{\phi}x)}{x} \ dx\\
 = &\ - 2 \text{Li}_2(\frac1{\phi})- 2 \text{Li}_2({-\phi})=4\ln^2\phi
\end{align}
where $\quad\text{Li}_2(\frac1{\phi})=\frac{\pi^2}{10}-\ln^2\phi\quad$ and $\quad\text{Li}_2({-\phi})=-\frac{\pi^2}{10}-\ln^2\phi$.

Whats $\phi$ here ?

@Ash_Blanc Golden ratio $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$

It's lil insane though the actual ans is in terms of $\pi$ not $\phi$

Though I got one idea this integral converts into $2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(-x^2+x+1)}{x} \rm{d}x$

$$I=\int \frac{\log(-x^2+x+1)}{x(1-x)} \,dx=\int \frac{\log(\phi-x)+\log \left(x-\frac{1}{\phi }\right)}{x(1-x)} \,dx$$
$$\frac 1 {x(1-x)}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x-1}$$
$$I=\int \frac{\log (\phi -x)}{x}\,dx-\int \frac{\log (\phi -x)}{x-1} \,dx+\int \frac{\log \left(x-\frac{1}{\phi }\right)}{x}\,dx-\int \frac{\log \left(x-\frac{1}{\phi }\right)}{x-1}\,dx$$
Four simple integrals

whats after this step ?

@Ash_Blanc nothing left

@Martin.s how to find out the value of last four integrals ??
